# Creating an array of Images and display one at random on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm trying to add my first ever extension for Apple Watch but having issues with creating an array for the app. When I run the app it crashes and I get this error show up at my array:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Below is my code, all I want is my image to change to a random image from the array every time the button is tapped:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    let runeArray = [UIImage(named: ("Fehu.png"))!, UIImage(named: ("Uruz.png"))!, UIImage(named: ("Thurisaz.png"))!]

    @IBOutlet var runeImage: WKInterfaceImage!

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        // Configure interface objects here.
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

    @IBAction func castRuneButton() {

        let randomRune = runeArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(runeArray.count)))]
        runeImage.setImage(randomRune)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Which line does it crash on? Getting the image from the array, or setting it on the view?

Comment: Almost certainly (at least) one of those image files cannot be found, so you get a crash on the force unwrap

Comment: Hi, the error I posted above appears beside the let runeArray line of code. I see when I created runeImage it’s a WKInterfaceImage which is new to me so is my array of UIImage correct? I’m unsure?

Comment: @Paulw11 I've checked my image names and they are typed perfectly so I think it's my syntax for the array is wrong?

Comment: Have you added the images or asset catalog to your watch app target?

Comment: @Paulw11 I've added a screenshot, hopefully I have done it correctly

Comment: You have to check the properties of that asset catalog and make sure it is enabled for both the iOS and watch targets

Comment: @Paulw11 If you want to write the answer below and i'll select it as correct answer as this worked perfectly, the iOS Target was not selected

Comment: Quick reminder, there's an answer below that could do with accepting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have selected both the iOS and watch extension targets for your asset catalog.